# converting crystal reports into jaspersoft

Tags: crystal-reports, jasper-reports

I have to convert multiple reports from crystal reports into jasper studio, is there any way to do it aside from manually dragging fields in each reports?

I did try manually converting reports, and it's a tedious task to do lol

Answer (score 0):

It seems , that you are out of luck on this one, because of legal Issues.

In this [thread](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/518811/migration-crystal-reports) (which is from 2007 but the last post is from 2017) it is mentioned that
"automated conversion of .RPTs is against the Crystal EULA..."

It appears that in this [Issues](https://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/2703) post it's mentioned that there are vendors which provide conversion services

I recommend doing more research about the topic on the [Jaspersoft Community Site](https://community.jaspersoft.com/search?query=crystal%20reports)

Comment: I saw that as well, too bad for me lol